# Python code that does subtracting and adding?

Tags: python

I am new to learning python, I see it's a simple language but my teacher thinks it's a good thing to give me very advanced tasks to complete, I have it due tomorrow so if anyone could manage to code this in, I will be greatly appreciated. Here is what he wants:

- Detect user input for the words: "add" and "sub" aka subtraction. if the wrong answer is given, it should re-ask the question.
- If the user chooses either, it should generate two numbers from 1-9, number 1 >= number 2, and the user should be asked the answer.
- If the answer is correct, it should move to the next round (our teacher said there must be 5 rounds, at each end of the round the code should ask the user to type "add" or "sub" again.
- if the user gives the wrong answer, it should re-ask the question.
- The code ends when all 5 rounds are done, or if the user types "end" at any time with a message saying "Goodbye".

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not meant to give you answers to questions. You are expected to make an effort to solve the problem then ask a specific question about an error you have.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I would love to solve it myself, but we didn't even take the classes for that yet, I searched the internet for the entire day and i can't manage to understand most of the stuff here.

Comment: Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: If your teacher gave work, search it up and try to get it. :)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally uncalled for people to post their homework here and have it solved, as StackOverflow is meant as a place that every question can help out a lot of people interested in your matter.
While I will not do your homework, here's what you can do:

- Use "while" statements for the input check and validation, which means it will keep asking if the input is different from the value you set as required for the loop to break.
- Use "If" statements for general validation checks.

What is most important though is that you take the time and read/watch tutorials that can help you get a better understanding of the language, as Stackoverflow is a place for questions of a specific nature and not a homework-solving/debugging service. Hope I could be of help!

I personally recommend the following resources for learning Python:

https://www.mikedane.com/

https://www.w3schools.com/

https://www.sololearn.com/

[Personal Playlist for learning Python](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSmVxBb1fjjvq2tRomG10Jk8UNfH3_yMc)

Comment: Thank you for your time, will try my best to do so.

Comment: No problem! If you found my answer useful, you could mark it as answered.